# Запятая после "затем"

Tags: пунктуация

Для ввода с клавитуры нужно щелкнуть мышкой внутри области поля даты. Затем, нужно ввести восемь цифр даты (без пробелов) и, после нажатия клавиши «Enter» получаем введённые данные.

*//пишу инструкцию, не всегда уверен в запятых

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Для ввода с клавитуры нужно щелкнуть мышкой внутри области поля даты. Затем нужно ввести восемь цифр даты без пробелов, и после нажатия клавиши «Enter» получаем введённые данные.***

ЗАТЕМ не является вводным словом, это обстоятельство, выраженное наречием: ввести (когда?) затем. Поэтому запятая не нужна.

Перед И запятая необходима, так как она разделяет два простых односоставных предложения в составе сложносочинённого: безличное и определённо-личное.

Answer (score 0):

Тут у Вас две лишние запятые. После "затем" запятая не нужна и после "и" тоже. Собственно, в обоих предложениях запятых нет.

Comment: Спасибо.

Ещё смущает форма "получаем", я обычно использую такую стилистику во всём документе, но в прошлый раз пришлось исправлять...

Comment: Запятая нужна перед И.